# Effitient way of Selecting row arrays in 2d Numpy Array falling into some Interval

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I would like to select row arrays which has certain columns falls into an interval object.
Say I have an interval object intv and a 2d numpy array X:

```
intv
# Interval(1.5, 2, closed='right')

X
# array([[1, 1, 2],
#       [2, 2, 4],
#       [3, 3, 9]])
```

At first I tried:

```
X[X[:,0] in intv]
```

However, an exception was thrown:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Then I tried list comprehension, and it works:

```
sel_idx = [X[j,0] in intv for j in range(len(X[:,0])) ]
X[sel_idx]
```

I wonder if there is any computational inexpensive and elegant way of solving this problem?

Comment: Do you mean `X[list(X[:,0] in intv)]`?

Comment: Hmmm, I am afraid not. Casting it to list throws the same error. Maybe I should clearify that I do not care if sel_idx is a list or numpy array.

Comment: `X[list(X[i,0] in intv for i in range(len(X)) )]`